# What is this CSS property : -internal-light-dark

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I was trying to style a select element with CSS only (what a dumb idea. I know) in **Edge**.
I noticed while looking to the browser default (user agent stylesheet) that these lines of style were applied:

```css
color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(59, 59, 59));
border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
```

I tried on Chrome 87 & Opera 71 and same default property is applied.
From what I've seen, Firefox doesn't apply this.

I tried to do a Google search for "-internal-light-dark" but found nothing. Can someone explain me what does this do?

Comment: Is this style changing in different browsers? If so, please submit more examples for each browser, and also post URL if it's public, this would help debug the issue.

Comment: There is [my site](http://www.anatole-sot.tech/projets/Calligraphie/) (where i noticed it first) but it seem to be applied on every select element by the browser.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, try a browser without extensions.

Comment: the attribute is still here even though I launched edge with : ```start msedge --disable-extensions```. I also tried with a fresh installation of Chrome and the attribute is there again.

Comment: Did you Google search with the double quotes? Prefixing a hyphen/dash/minus character implies you want to exclude that search term!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the commit when it was added https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/5c56063a3a156531e2e368047bec5cfd48b2ff21

Then renamed https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/42267a718b56e0da01b82c4aee8b342f24e45c1b

Here are more related commits https://github.com/chromium/chromium/search?p=2&q=internal-light-dark&type=commits

From what I understand from the source, it's an internal (like the name implies) property used by chromium based browsers (that's why firefox ignores it) to store a pair or light/dark colors to use depending on the system's color schema.

EDIT: since it's not standard CSS I would suggest to not use them unless you really REALLY need to have some special rule for chromium-based browsers

EDIT: here you can see how they use it internally https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/5c56063a3a156531e2e368047bec5cfd48b2ff21#diff-60fdf3dc7f2f69a2b744d617c2c9ed1c293c1d2309f934d6ae285970ad8e8002R70

```
    const CSSColorValue& color_value = To<CSSColorValue>(
        WebColorScheme::kLight ? pair->First() : pair->Second());
    return color_value.Value();
```

If the color schema is `light` it uses the first value, else, the second.